# Click outside of div and more

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want login area (in code below) to toggle on login button click. Also, I need login area hidden when clicked anywhere outside of login area, but not on login button.

```
<button id="loginBtn">Login</button>

<div id="loginArea">
   <!-- here is login form -->
</div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @eomeroff: You have 1151 rep - surely you should know by now that people will ask you - 'what have you tried so far'...

Comment: how about using selector :not ?

Comment: @Westie I do not have 1151 any more. And I do not see any one asking what have I tried. What if I do not have a clue how to try. This is specific question that could not research. Honestly I do not see the reason why 5 down votes. Hope  the question will be useful for someone.

Comment: @Ravi I can not use UI modal dialog box. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('#loginBtn, #loginArea').on('click', function(e) {
        $('#loginArea').show();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('body').on('click', function() {
        $('#loginArea').hide();
    });
});
```

If the click is within the login area or on the button, then the event will not make it to the second handler to hide the login area.

Answer (score 2):

Using:

```
$('body').on('click', '#loginBtn', function(){
    $('#loginArea').show();
});
```

Will show the login, while the following will remove it when you click outside of it:

```
$(document).on('click', 'body:not(#loginArea)', function(){
    $('#loginArea').hide();
});
```

Comment: .remove() will remove the div from the DOM.

Comment: @Dogoku Ah good catch! Updated.

Answer (score -1):

How's that?

```
$('#loginBtn').click(function (e) {
   $('#loginArea').toggle();
   e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on('click',function () {
    $('#loginArea').hide();
});
```

Comment: This will hide the login box even when you click inside it.

Comment: no it wont, `e.stopPropagation()` stops event bubbling to the other handler